# How do GPT-style LLMs produce embeddings?

Tags: large-language-model

I'm aware of how image models produce embeddings. You feed an image to the model and look at the activations in one of the last layers of the model. I don't think this approach generalizes to LLM models though.

For example, lets say you embed a document using a GPT model. I could envision the embedding getting calculated in a variety of ways (all use one of the last layers in the LLM model):

- The LLM produces an embedding for each output token in the document and averages all of the tokens' embeddings to arrive at a document-level embedding
- The LLM returns only the last token's embedding
- The LLM concatenates all output token embeddings where the embedding size is equal to the context length. Shorter documents with leftover context window get padded (perhaps with 0s) so that embedding dimensions are constant across all documents

Is there a broad pattern that most models (other than those of the GPT variety) use to produce embeddings or are the methods wildly different from say GPT-3 to Llama-2?

Answer (score 4):

I found a helpful research [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.10005.pdf) by [OpenAI](https://openai.com/blog/introducing-text-and-code-embeddings) that answered my question.

Generative, auto-regressive models aren't well suited for embeddings because their understanding of the input is spread out over multiple hidden states. You need to train a model whose specific purpose is to produce embeddings. Typically this is a transformer encoder, and in such cases you take the hidden state from the last layer of the last "end of sequence" token. This means that the model's understanding is concentrated in a single place.

Relevant excerpts from the paper below.

Generative models aren't well suited for performing predictions:

> In generative models, the information about the input is typically distributed over multiple hidden states of the model. While some generative models can learn a single representation of the input, most autoregressive Transformer models do not

You need a purpose-built embeddings model:

> Embedding models are explicitly optimized to learn a low dimensional representation that captures the semantic meaning of the input

You use a transformer encoder, and use the hidden state from the last layer of the last token:

> Given a training pair (x, y), a Transformer (Vaswani et al., 2017) encoder E is used to process x and y independently. The encoder maps the input to a dense vector representation or embedding (Figure 2). We insert two special token delimiters, [SOS] and [EOS], to the start and end of the input sequence respectively. The hidden state from the last layer corresponding to the special token [EOS] is considered as the embedding of the input sequence.

Answer (score 3):

This approach doesn't generalize to GPT-like (autoregressive) models, but it is exactly how BERT and similar models generate embeddings.

Getting embeddings from LLaMA-2 would be a lot of work, but can be done. You need to finetune the model though, and the results typically aren't as good as what BERT or T5 gives you.

Comment: Why would you need to fine-tune to get embeddings?

Comment: Upvoted because today I learned that you're correct that taking embeddings doesn't generalize to GPT-like auto-regressive models.